# C Keep a running signal array sorted

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to improve the speed of my current program, the program logs data from multiple sensors but one part in specific is very slow.

In this part I store the signal data in an integer array of size 50 and extract the maximum and minimum to get a (crude) indication of the amplitude. This is done for 3 sensors every second but sorting the array to get the minimum and maximum takes a very long time.

My first thought was storing the data in a sorted list, but how to keep track of what was the last signal point that has to be removed?

The current code:

```
    static int movement[AD_SENSORS][AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE];
    static int totals[AD_SENSORS];
    int movement_sorted[AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE];
    int difference = 0;
    static unsigned int i; // Movement index
    int k = 0;

    //Update positions
    if (++i>(AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE-1)){i=0;} //increment index of movement array

    //Initialise signal value
    struct tty_data_t *Current = NULL;
    Current = head_tty;

    //Add signals to movement array
    while (Current != NULL){
        totals[Current->ID] = totals[Current->ID] - movement[Current->ID][i];
        movement[Current->ID][i] = Current->AD_signal;
        totals[Current->ID] = totals[Current->ID] + movement[Current->ID][i];
        Current->AD_average = totals[Current->ID] / AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE;
        for (k = 0; k<AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE; k++){
            movement_sorted[k] = movement[Current->ID][k];
        }
        qsort (movement_sorted, AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE, sizeof(int), Compare);
        Current->AD_amplitude = movement_sorted[AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE-1] - movement_sorted[0];
        difference += movement_sorted[AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE-1] - movement_sorted[0];
        Current = Current->next;
    }
    g_movement = difference;
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the last signal point? Why do not you store just the maximum and minimum signals and update one of them each time if needed?

Comment: 'sorting the array to get the minimum and maximum takes a very long time' really? 'integer array of size 50', '3 sensors every second'??   What are you running on, an abacus?  :)   Plus, what @Michael says - keep a running max/min.

Comment: Well actually now it doesnt take a long time but there's a plan to increase it to 8 sensors at 100 times per second on a Raspberry Pi and looking at callgrind this function takes 70% of the time.
*And how to keep track of max/min if the next datapoint is added to the end of the array and the first is removed, how do i know what the max/min is then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting fifty elements shouldn't take very long, it should certainly be able to do that in under a third of a second.

However, you probably don't actually *need* to sort. Assuming you have a rolling array of the last fifty elements, you only need to adjust the `min` and `max` (and the count of elements matching them, `mincount` and `maxcount`) under limited circumstances. I'll givve you the steps for a maximum value only but it's easy just to duplicate the logic for a minimum as well. These are all mutually exclusive situations and should be checked in the order given (the first match you find precludes all others following it):

- When adding an element to an empty list, set `max` to that element and set `maxcount` to one.
- If you're adding the same value that you're removing, do nothing.
- If you're adding a value that's the same as `max`, just add one to `maxcount`.
- If you're adding a value that's larger than the current `max`, set `max` to that value and set `maxcount` to one.
  If the value you're removing is the same as `max` and `maxcount` is greater than one, simply decrement `maxcount`.
- Otherwise, if the value you're removing is equal to the current `max` (at this point, `maxcount` must be one), scan the items in the list to recalculate the new `max` and set the counts accordingly.

The only *possibly* costly option there is the last one and I'd expect it to occur reasonably rarely. In any case, searching an array of size fifty with a couple of comparisons per iteration should still be blindingly fast.

And don't be *too* concerned about performance yet. Even eight sensors at a hundred readings per second each will only give you 800 data points. With a data set that small, sorting may be a fool's errand since scanning that many items sequentially will still be very fast (especially if you don't have to do it *every* time the rolling data is updated.

Comment: Thanks I was certainly making the problem more difficult then it was reading this, and again at the moment it is indeed very fast but I'm already improving it for the next step where the read out speed and sensor amount is increased.

Comment: @Enigma1991, even 800 elements can be scanned sequentially in very quick time. I'd leave sorting out until there's an *actual* performance problem.

Comment: I've updated the code and tried it at full speed, I do see an increase of 8 measurements per second and the function now only shows at the bottom of callgrind, I'm now reading 8 sensors at 49 times per second and the array is 50 points long so about 1 second. This is all running on a raspberry pi 2 but now the sqlite execute shows in the top of callgrind so the problem indeed lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sorting just to get the maximum and minimum values and not some other reason that is not included in the question, then you don't need to.
You already have the following loop in your code:

```
for (k = 0; k < AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE; k++){
            movement_sorted[k] = movement[Current->ID][k];
        }
```

Instead of copying the array to sort it (in `O(nlogn)` time) just check if each element is the maximum or the minimum and get them in `O(n)` time.

```
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
for (k = 0; k<AD_MOVEMENT_SIZE; k++){
            if (movement[Current->ID][k] < min) min = movement[Current->ID][k];
            if (movement[Current->ID][k] > max) max = movement[Current->ID][k];
        }
```

Disclaimer: I know that big-O notation doesn't say much in arrays of 50 elements, but it is important in the more general case